# Trouble with HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-plugin

I am writing plugin, which inlines some code. And I have troubles with internal webpack plugin

#### **Intro**

My aim is to transpile this code

```js
// a.js

export const getFoo = x => x.foo;

// b.js
import {getFoo} from './a.js';

export const func = x => getFoo(x);
```

to this one

```js
// b.js
export const func = x => x.foo;
```

Using [this comment](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/10081#issuecomment-565786166) I implemented such logic

1. Hook on `compiler.hooks.beforeCompile` and find all imports of transpiled modules with `parser.hooks.importSpecifier` and
2. Then using the same `compiler` hook, I find all `CallExpression`s and remember all functions which will be transpiled and their position
3. In `compiler.hooks.compilation` in `compilation.hooks.buildModule` I add template dependency which will replace CallExpressions with MemberExpression

#### **The problem**

Webpack has internal plugin `HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency`. Apparently, it does the same logic replacing

```js
import {getFoo} from './a.js';

export const func = x => x.foo;
```

with

```js
"use strict";
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "a", function() { return func; });
/* harmony import */ var _getters_uno__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__(0);

const func = x => {
  // NEXT LINE IS THE RESULT OF `HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency` WORK
  return Object(_getters_uno__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[/* getFoo */ "e"])(x);
};
```

My problem is that both plugins (mine and `HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency`) remembers the original source and original places of `CallExpression`s. The result of both plugins is invalid code:

```js
return Object(_getters_uno__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__[/* getFoo */ "e"])x.foo);
```

#### **The question**

Is there a way how to give `HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency` the result of my plugin? I've tried to reparse module in `compilation` phase, but whith no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with patching `replacements` object in source in `succeedBuild` hook

```js
source.replacements = source.replacements
  .filter(r => !r.content.includes(`/* ${callExpression.callee.name} */`));
```

Still wonder if there is a better solution